# Using libxml2 WITHOUT zlib

Tags: zlib, libxml2

we are using libxml2 with zlib. There is an option to build libxml2 WITHOUT zlib as well. What is the difference? is performance affected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it.

There is an explicit compiling configuration option for excluding zib.

from libxml2 [FAQ](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html)

> What other libraries are needed to compile/install libxml2 ?
>
> Libxml2 does not require any other library, the normal C ANSI API
>   should be sufficient (please report any violation to this rule you may
>   find).
>
> However if found at configuration time libxml2 will detect and use the
>   following libs:
>
> ```
> libz : a highly portable and available widely compression library.
> iconv: a powerful character encoding conversion library.
> ```

The option itself depends by the compilation environment.
Take a look at this article
http://www.tuan.nguoianphu.com/LibXML2_compile_for_Linux_Solaris_Windows

libxml uses zlib for reading or writing to compressed files directly. So if you do not need this functionality then the library can be removed.